# nunjucks migration from swig

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

I have an app already built using swig as the templating engine; however, due to recent upgrades I'm having to migrate to nunjucks.  I have a page being rendered, but no styles or javascript are being attached.  The code worked with swig, but it doesn't appear to be pulling in the content of the stylesheets or JavaScript files.

```
   // setup db
mongoose.connect(secrets.db);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
console.error('MongoDB Connection Error. Make sure MongoDB is running.');
});

var corsOptions = {
origin: '*'
};

// express setup
var app = express();



// This is where all the magic happens!

nunjucks.configure(path.join(__dirname, 'views'), {
autoescape: true,
express: app,
noCache : app.get('env') === 'development',
watch: true
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index.html');
});
app.locals._ = lodash;
app.locals.stripePubKey = secrets.stripeOptions.stripePubKey;


app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(compress);
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
if(app.get('env') !== 'production'){
app.use('/styles', express.static(__dirname + '/../.tmp/styles'));
// app.use('/', routes.styleguide);
}

app.use(session({
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {
maxAge: 60 * 1000 // 1 minute
},
secret: secrets.sessionSecret,
store: new MongoStore({
url: secrets.db,
auto_reconnect: true
})
}));

// setup passport authentication
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// other
app.use(flash());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

var passportMiddleware = require('./middleware/passport');
passportMiddleware(passport);

// setup view helper
app.use(viewHelper);

// setup routes
var routes = require('./routes');
routes(app, passport);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(errorHandler.notFound);

/// error handlers
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(errorHandler.development);
} else {
app.use(errorHandler.production);
}

module.exports = app;
```

It's not throwing any errors, just no content being pulled in for styles or JavaScript.

Comment: Are you attach styles/js as `{% include some-file %}` or as usual html? I think that your problem is incorrect paths for static files. You can check it: open browser console `F12` and go to network tab (see response code).

Comment: @AikonMogwai, they were attached with usual html.

Comment: Therefore it's a not nunjucks problem. Check static paths in code.